# How to load new data after click next or back Fullcalendar

Tags: c#, ajax, fullcalendar

I am using Fullcalendar plugin which is integrated with my ASP.NET MVC project. My main task consists of creating a schedule of reservations. I have written the code which is responsible for displaying events("Buttons") for specific date, and it works fine!. Code below:

```
var calendar = $("#calendar").fullCalendar({
        weekends: false
         , lang: 'pl',
         header: {
             left:'',
             center: 'title',
             right: 'today prev,next'
         }, height: 630, week: true, columnFormat: 'dd M/D', minTime: '8:00', maxTime: '20:00', selectable: true,
        allDaySlot: false, eventColor: '#F6A828',       
        events: function (start, end, timezone, callback) {


            $.ajax({
                url: '/Dentist/GetEvents/',
                type: 'POST',
                contentType: "application/json",
                success: function (json) {
                    if (json.isRedirect) {
                        window.location.href = json.redirectUrl;
                    }
                    callback(json)
                    //
                }
            });           
        },
    })
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('changeView', 'agendaWeek');
```

and method GetEvents in C#

```
public JsonResult GetEvents()
    {
        if (Session["DoctorID"] == null)
        {
            return Json(new { redirectUrl = Url.Action("Terminarz", "Recepcjonista"), isRedirect = true });
        }
        var listEvent = new List<CallendarEvent>();

        List<CallendarEvent> list = TermRepository.GetAllEventsByDoctorId((int)Session["DoctorID"]);
        int licznik = 1;
        foreach (var item in list)
        {
            int count = Size(item.id, item.From, item.To);
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            {
                listEvent.Add(new CallendarEvent()
                {
                    id = licznik,
                    day = item.day,
                    Title = item.Title,
                    From = GetDay(item.day).AddHours(item.From.TimeOfDay.Hours).AddMinutes(item.From.TimeOfDay.Minutes).AddMinutes(i * 30),
                    To = GetDay(item.day).AddHours(item.From.TimeOfDay.Hours).AddMinutes(item.From.TimeOfDay.Minutes).AddMinutes(i * 30).AddMinutes(30)
                });
                licznik++;
            }
        }

         var listEvent2 = from l in listEvent
                        select new
                        {
                            id = l.id,
                            //day = l.day,
                            //Title = l.Title,
                            start = l.From,
                            end = l.To,
                            color = "#88CD23"
                        };

        return Json(listEvent2, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

and now I would like to handle next and back buttons and change start date, end +7 day. I wrote something like this, but doesn't work
  C#

```
public JsonResult GetEventsAdd(int move)
    {
        //all the same method as in GetEvents, but added days

                listEvent.Add(new CallendarEvent()
                {
                    id = licznik,
                    day = item.day,
                    Title = item.Title,
                    From = GetDay(item.day).AddHours(item.From.TimeOfDay.Hours).AddMinutes(item.From.TimeOfDay.Minutes).AddMinutes(i * 30).AddDays(move),
                    To = GetDay(item.day).AddHours(item.From.TimeOfDay.Hours).AddMinutes(item.From.TimeOfDay.Minutes).AddMinutes(i * 30).AddMinutes(30).AddDays(move)
                });
                licznik++;
            }
        }

       //all the same method as in GetEvents

        return Json(listEvent2, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

and script was changed

```
events: function (start, end, timezone, callback) {
            var data = { "move": 7 }

            $.ajax({
                url: '/Dentist/GetEvents/',
                type: 'POST',
                //data: JSON.stringify(calendar),
                //datatype: "json",
                contentType: "application/json",
                success: function (json) {
                    if (json.isRedirect) {
                        window.location.href = json.redirectUrl;
                    }
                    callback(json)
                    //
                }
            });

            $(".fc-next-button").one("click", function () {

                $.ajax({
                    url: '/Dentist/GetEventsAdd/',
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: JSON.stringify(data),
                    datatype: "json",
                    contentType: "application/json",
                    success: function (json) {
                        if (json.isRedirect) {
                            window.location.href = json.redirectUrl;
                        }
                        callback(json)
                        //$('#calendar').fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
                    }
                });
            });
```

how can I get such a solution?

Answer (score 1):

The AJAX call that fullcalendar makes passes the start and end date range for the current view. It will then call that again, only if it doesn't have the date stored.
so in your /Dentist/GetEvents/
grab the "GET" variables: "START" and "END".
return the events that are in that range.

then simply use the native 'next', 'prev' buttons from fullcalendar and let it do its thing.